# Not sure why I'm getting this output for first element in char array

Tags: c, string, algorithm

[image: Output]

I'm getting a strange output for the first process ID name, not sure why. Maybe the way i'm telling it to print the char array?

CODE BELOW:

int main(){

```
int a; //variable used for: total number of processes
int i,j,k,l; //used for loops
int t1; //temporary variables
int burst[10],ttime[10],wait[10];
char process_name[10][11]; // array for storing up to 10 strings, with each up to length of 10 characters
char process_name_temp[10][11]; //temp variable for process name

float wait_time,wait_time_avg;



/*Pre-Fill burst and wait arrays with times of 0*/
for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    burst[i]=0;
    wait[i]=0;
}

wait_time_avg = 0; //set the wait time average to zero

printf("Please Enter Total Number of Processes Desired\n"); //

scanf("%d",&a); //get input from user:total number of processes

/*get user input from user: burst time for each process, process name for each process*/
for(i=0;i<a;i++){

    printf("Please Enter Process Name(one word)\n");
    scanf("%s", &process_name[i][11]);
    printf("Please Enter Burst Time\n");
    scanf("%d", &burst[i]);

}

for(i=0;i<a;i++){

    for(j=1;j<a;j++){

        if(burst[i]>burst[j]){

            t1 = burst[i];
            process_name_temp[i][11] = process_name[i][11];
            burst[i] = burst[j];
            process_name[i][11] = process_name[j][11];
            burst[j] = t1;
            process_name[j][11] = process_name_temp[j][11];

        }
    }

wait[0] = 0;

for(i=0;i<a;i++)

    wait[i+1] = wait[i] + burst[i];

for(i=0;i<a;i++){

    //ttime[i] = wait[i] + burst[i];
    wait_time_avg = 0;
    wait_time = 0;
    wait_time_avg = wait_time_avg + wait[i];

}

wait_time_avg = wait_time_avg/a;

printf("\n\t Process ID \t Waiting Time \t Burst Time \n");

for(i=0;i<a;i++)

    printf("\t %s \t\t %d \t\t\t %d \n\n", process_name[i],wait[i],burst[i]);
    printf("Waiting Time Average: %f \n", wait_time_avg);
}
```

return 0;

}

If anyone could help me that would be great. It's probably an easy fix - something little I missed or overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: Do not post images of text!

Answer (score 3):

1. In your `scanf("%s", &process_name[i][11]);`. This passes a pointer to one element after the end of the `process_name` array. So your `scanf()` call is wrong, it should be

   ```
   scanf("%10s", process_name[i]);
   ```

   hence the program is exhibiting undefined behavior due to the `process_name` array being initialized incorrectly.
2. You MUST check the return value from `scanf()` specially for the `"%d"` specifier. If you don't, you riks also your program invoking undefined behavior because of reading uninitialized data.
3. You should check that `a < 10` before starting the `for` loop. So after asking the user for the number of items, ensure that the user did type something reasonable/valid.
4. In the nested for loops in your code you access one element past the last element in every array. The indexes go from `0` to `N - 1`, so accessing `x[N]` is not going to work as expected.

Comment: That tells it to look for 10 chars?? Could you explain why exactly? Thanks for the quick response by the way!

Comment: @lsch91 I don't understand your new question.

Comment: The "%10s" part , what exactly does the number 10 between the % and s do?

Comment: It prevents `scanf()` from reading more than 10 characters from the user.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks. You mentioned above that "process_name" array is initialized incorrectly. Where did I do that? PS. Please feel free to tear my code apart - I'm here to learn!

Comment: @lsch91 the array was not initialised, so when you wrote to the wrong place, what was printed later made no sense. Local variables only get initialised when you explicitly do so.

Comment: okay I initialized the 2D array with zeros by adding this line->
memset(process_name, 0, sizeof(process_name[0][0])*11*10); 

however, first process name still not appearing in the right spot

Comment: @lsch91 Don't do something just to **HIDE** the bug, use a debugger and visualize memory at runtime if you can or use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) if you are on the appropriate platform.